Adobe not recognizing LTV-enable even if OCSPs and Certs are setted
I'm trying to sign a PDF file using my API and I want to obtain LTV-enable so I included OCSPs and Certs in DSS entry. I used C++ with PDFNet to sign, but I think I did not encoded correctly the OCSPs and Certs. The OCSP server is setted locally with openssl ocsp and I use a self-signed CA to issue the signing certificate which is then used in PFX file. I tried to see the ocsp response at it seems ok:
SEQUENCE
  ENUMERATED 0
  [0]
    SEQUENCE
      ObjectIdentifier ocspBasic (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 48 1 1)
      OCTETSTRING, encapsulates
        SEQUENCE
          SEQUENCE
            [1]
              SEQUENCE
                SET
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier countryName (2 5 4 6)
                    PrintableString 'RO'
                SET
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier stateOrProvinceName (2 5 4 8)
                    UTF8String 'Romania'
                SET
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier organizationName (2 5 4 10)
                    UTF8String 'MTA'
                SET
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
                    UTF8String 'IT'
                SET
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier commonName (2 5 4 3)
                    UTF8String 'ocsp'
                SET
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier emailAddress (1 2 840 113549 1 9 1)
                    IA5String '-'
            GeneralizedTime 20240401154921Z
            SEQUENCE
              SEQUENCE
                SEQUENCE
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier sha1 (1 3 14 3 2 26)
                    NULL
                  OCTETSTRING 0491c1904ccb05dd4ccc33724e75aa78f7fa68f6
                  OCTETSTRING 3851e5575562b1ff364de4741ab503e2a23b5f66
                  INTEGER 03
                [0] 
                GeneralizedTime 20240401154921Z
          SEQUENCE
            ObjectIdentifier SHA256withRSA (1 2 840 113549 1 1 11)
            NULL
          BITSTRING 0031160974a4f06840ea42d6fd465809..(total 257bytes)..0bc6bc861a1eb262dc2841da3bc27dea
          [0]
            SEQUENCE
              SEQUENCE
                SEQUENCE
                  [0]
                    INTEGER 02
                  INTEGER 00
                  SEQUENCE
                    ObjectIdentifier SHA256withRSA (1 2 840 113549 1 1 11)
                    NULL
                  SEQUENCE
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier countryName (2 5 4 6)
                        PrintableString 'RO'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier stateOrProvinceName (2 5 4 8)
                        UTF8String 'Romania'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier localityName (2 5 4 7)
                        UTF8String 'Bucharest'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier organizationName (2 5 4 10)
                        UTF8String 'MTA'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
                        UTF8String 'IT'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier commonName (2 5 4 3)
                        UTF8String 'mta'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier emailAddress (1 2 840 113549 1 9 1)
                        IA5String '-'
                  SEQUENCE
                    UTCTime 240326164102Z
                    UTCTime 250326164102Z
                  SEQUENCE
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier countryName (2 5 4 6)
                        PrintableString 'RO'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier stateOrProvinceName (2 5 4 8)
                        UTF8String 'Romania'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier organizationName (2 5 4 10)
                        UTF8String 'MTA'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
                        UTF8String 'IT'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier commonName (2 5 4 3)
                        UTF8String 'ocsp'
                    SET
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier emailAddress (1 2 840 113549 1 9 1)
                        IA5String '-'
                  SEQUENCE
                    SEQUENCE
                      ObjectIdentifier rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
                      NULL
                    BITSTRING, encapsulates
                      SEQUENCE
                        INTEGER 00b723be06b0872d354ceaa7c7f4ce6e..(total 257bytes)..90ee6fc567c79622085af4e971621ecd
                        INTEGER 010001
                  [3]
                    SEQUENCE
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier authorityInfoAccess (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 1 1)
                        OCTETSTRING, encapsulates
                          SEQUENCE
                            SEQUENCE
                              ObjectIdentifier ocsp (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 48 1)
                              [6] http://127.0.0.1:8888
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier basicConstraints (2 5 29 19)
                        OCTETSTRING, encapsulates
                          SEQUENCE {}
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier subjectKeyIdentifier (2 5 29 14)
                        OCTETSTRING, encapsulates
                          OCTETSTRING 48dae018e53cda3ba7cddd5ceae759f6a215c0a0
                      SEQUENCE
                        ObjectIdentifier authorityKeyIdentifier (2 5 29 35)
                        OCTETSTRING, encapsulates
                          SEQUENCE
                            [0] 3851e5575562b1ff364de4741ab503e2a23b5f66
                SEQUENCE
                  ObjectIdentifier SHA256withRSA (1 2 840 113549 1 1 11)
                  NULL
                BITSTRING 003d0fcdfe56c73ab7bd6c1c15bda780..(total 129bytes)..b07b8fd9e006bee6d4dd3f5a8750c0ef

I used this code (with some hardcoded paths because I try to figure out why is not working and writting and then reading certificates again because they have to be DER-encoded as far as I know):
PDFDoc enableLT(PDFDoc doc, PadesSignatureLTHandler& handler, string oscpRevocationCertFilePath, string timestampRevocation) {
    Obj root = doc.GetRoot();
    Obj dssDictionary = doc.CreateIndirectDict();
    Obj ocspArray = doc.CreateIndirectArray();
    Obj certsArray = doc.CreateIndirectArray();

    STACK_OF(X509)* chain = handler.get_x509_chain();

    for (int i = 0; i < sk_X509_num(chain); ++i) {
        X509* cert = sk_X509_value(chain, i);
        int der_cert_buffer_length = i2d_X509(cert, NULL);
        if (der_cert_buffer_length <= 0) {
            exit(1);
        }
        unsigned char* der_cert_buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(der_cert_buffer_length * sizeof(unsigned char));
        unsigned char*copy = der_cert_buffer;
        i2d_X509(cert, &copy);

        std::string certFileName = "./Temporary/cert_" + std::to_string(i) + ".der";
        FILE* f = fopen(certFileName.c_str(), "wb");
        if (!f) {
            // Handle error
        }
        fwrite(der_cert_buffer, 1, der_cert_buffer_length, f);
        fclose(f);

        Filters::MappedFile certMappedFile(certFileName);
        Filters::FilterReader certFilterReader(certMappedFile);
        Obj certStream = doc.CreateIndirectStream(certFilterReader);

        certsArray.PushBack(certStream);

        std::remove(certFileName.c_str());
        free(der_cert_buffer);
    }


    FILE* tsa_pem = fopen("./Certificate/tsa.crt", "rb");
    X509* tsa = X509_new();
    PEM_read_X509(tsa_pem, &tsa, NULL, NULL);
    int tsa_len = i2d_X509(tsa, NULL);
    if (tsa_len <= 0)
    {
        //throw
    }
    unsigned char* tsa_buff = (unsigned char*)malloc(tsa_len * sizeof(unsigned char));
    unsigned char* copy = tsa_buff;
    i2d_X509(tsa, &copy);
    fclose(tsa_pem);

    FILE* f = fopen("./Certificate/tsa_cer.der", "wb");
    if (!f) {
        // Handle error
    }
    fwrite(tsa_buff, 1, tsa_len, f);
    fclose(f);
        
    FILE* root_tsa_pem = fopen("./Certificate/cacert.pem", "rb");
    X509* tsa_root = X509_new();
    PEM_read_X509(root_tsa_pem, &tsa_root, NULL, NULL);
    tsa_len = i2d_X509(tsa_root, NULL);
    if (tsa_len <= 0)
    {
        //throw
    }
    tsa_buff = (unsigned char*)malloc(tsa_len * sizeof(unsigned char));
    copy = tsa_buff;
    i2d_X509(tsa_root, &copy);
    fclose(root_tsa_pem);

    f = fopen("./Certificate/tsa_root_cer.der", "wb");
    if (!f) {
        // Handle error
    }
    fwrite(tsa_buff, 1, tsa_len, f);
    fclose(f);
    
    Filters::MappedFile tsaCertFile("./Certificate/tsa_cer.der");
    Filters::FilterReader tsaCertFileReader(tsaCertFile);
    Obj tsaCertStream = doc.CreateIndirectStream(tsaCertFileReader);
    certsArray.PushBack(tsaCertStream);

    Filters::MappedFile caTsaCertFile("./Certificate/tsa_root_cer.der");
    Filters::FilterReader caTsaCertFileReader(caTsaCertFile);
    Obj caTsaCertStream = doc.CreateIndirectStream(caTsaCertFileReader);
    certsArray.PushBack(caTsaCertStream);

    
    Filters::MappedFile ocspCertFile1(oscpRevocationCertFilePath);
    Filters::FilterReader ocspCertFileReader1(ocspCertFile1);
    Obj ocspCertStream1 = doc.CreateIndirectStream(ocspCertFileReader1);
    ocspArray.PushBack(ocspCertStream1);


    dssDictionary.PutName("Type", "DSS");
    dssDictionary.Put("OCSPs", ocspArray);
    dssDictionary.Put("Certs", certsArray);
    root.Put("DSS", dssDictionary);

    return doc;
}

I have already the OCSP responses for both signing certificate and TSA certificate (I obtained them earlier in the code).
I attach them here in a Google Drive link:
Google drive together with the file signed.
When I try to open it with Adobe, the signature is valid, but not LTV-enable.
I used some code from Another topic, but for me it didn't work.

How does the output from this forum post work for you?
https://community.apryse.com/t/how-do-i-create-and-sign-a-digital-signature-with-ltv/7315

Thank you for the link! I've already seen it, but I was asking to put them using low-level functions, not something like this !digsig_field.EnableLTVOfflineVerification(timestampVerificationResult). And the code was in C#, I found the version in C++ also, but, at least for me, it didn't work.

Why is low level important for you? Why not use the official APIs?

I  want to do it flexible. For example. now I try to retrieve the CaIssuers url from every certificate and then get them with an request. I include them in the file and also the ocsps responses. The code provided in the question text was the first version. If I use PdfNET is forcing me to use something like this:
opts.AddTrustedCertificate(in_timestamp_authority_root_certificate_path); which is supposing that you already retrieved the CA of the TSA and that you saved it locally. The question was in the direction of OCSP responses not recognizing more than using PDFNet. But thank you a lot!
